# React Navigation - remove components from navigation state and navigate to Screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using React Navigation as a router in my React Native app. I have a problem, which is that when I navigate between screens, hooks that were previously created when the screens we previously rendered, still exist.

I have a completely flat router:

```js
const AppRouter = () => {
    const Stack = createStackNavigator();

    return (
        <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
            <Stack.Navigator headerMode={false}>
                <Stack.Screen
                    component={Landing}
                    name="Landing"
                    options={fadeAnimation}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    component={LogInOrSignUp}
                    name="LogInOrSignUp"
                    options={fadeAnimation}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    component={Dashboard}
                    name="Dashboard"
                    options={horizontalAnimation}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    component={Loader}
                    name="Loader"
                    options={horizontalAnimation}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    component={WakingFromKilled}
                    name="Connecting"
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    component={EnterPhoneNumber}
                    name="EnterPhoneNumber"
                    options={horizontalAnimation}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    component={EnterSmsCode}
                    name="EnterSmsCode"
                    options={horizontalAnimation}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    component={CompleteProfile}
                    name="CompleteProfile"
                    options={horizontalAnimation}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    component={Contacts}
                    name="Contacts"
                    options={horizontalAnimation}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    component={TimeInput}
                    name="TimeInput"
                    options={horizontalAnimation}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    component={InCallContainer}
                    name="InCallContainer"
                    options={horizontalAnimation}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    component={ConnectingController}
                    name="ConnectingController"
                    options={horizontalAnimation}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    component={AccountModal}
                    name="AccountModal"
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    component={NoInternetConnection}
                    name="NoInternetConnection"
                    options={horizontalAnimation}
                />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};
```

When I navigate from `Dashboard > TimeInput > InCallContainer > Dashboard > TimeInput > InCallContainer`, the hooks that were created in `InCallContainer` the first time it was visited still exist when it is visited for the second time.

I am navigating using the methods:

```js
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
import * as React from 'react';

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

export function navigate(...args) {
    navigationRef.current.navigate(...args);
}
```

Then:

```js
RootNavigation.navigate('InCallContainer');
```

I can tell the hooks are being created multiple times because if I log inside the components that use those hooks, every time I navigate to them I get one more log. So two logs when I visit the screen for the second time and so on.

I want to be able to navigate to the Dashboard for the second time and when I do, unmount / remove all components from memory that came before this navigation.

I have tried replace, reset, push, popToTop but none of them have the desired effect.

How can I achieve this?

TIA

#### Update:

I need to programmatically navigate to `InCallContainer` from inside a Redux Thunk:

```js
export const answerCall = (calleeName) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { session, callType } = getState().callData;
    acceptCall(session, { calleeNameFromOwnContacts: calleeName });
    dispatch(callData({ callState: INCOMING }));
    stopRingtone();
    RootNavigation.navigate('InCallContainer');
    InCallManager.start({ media: callType === VIDEO ? 'video' : 'audio' });
    InCallManager.turnScreenOn();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

using `navigate` to route already in navigation history don't create new route it just navigate to it. 
you need to use `push` instead of `navigate` as `RootNavigation.push('InCallContainer')`.

and `push` will create new route.

read about [Navigate to a route multiple times](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating/#navigate-to-a-route-multiple-times).

this example show differens between `push` and `navigate` try snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/@ahmed_gaber/push).

- when use `navigate` the visit times increased +1
- but use `push` start new route with first visit time.

[image]

the code :

```js
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';



function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {

    const [visitTimes, setVisitTimes] = React.useState(0);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
            setVisitTimes(v => v + 1);
        });

        return unsubscribe;
    }, [navigation]);


    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Home visitTimes :</Text>
            <Text style={{padding: 20, fontSize : 80, fontWeight : "700"}}>{visitTimes}</Text>
            <Button
                title="push"
                onPress={() => navigation.push('Details')}
            />
        </View>
    );
}





function DetailsScreen({ navigation }) {


    const [visitTimes, setVisitTimes] = React.useState(0);


    React.useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
            setVisitTimes(v => v + 1);
        });

        return unsubscribe;
    }, [navigation]);


    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Details visitTimes :</Text>
            <Text style={{padding: 20, fontSize : 80, fontWeight : "700"}}>{visitTimes}</Text>
            <Button
                title="navigate"
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
                <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Detailed and underrated answer, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

The screen **InCallContainer** has not unmounted and when we are about to open the screen with the same key in the same navigator it doesn't re-render it shares its instance so if you are about to re-render it with its hooks then you have to create separate navigators.

Comment: Ok thank you @Jignesh - could you provide a quick example of how I should do this? Also if I do not want the same instance of the component when I navigate to it, will this also include all child components?

Comment: How would you like to implement the navigation of the screens as here we have to create a separate navigator?

Comment: Every time I navigate to 'InCallContainer' it must be a completely new instance of that component and every child component and hook must be a completely new instance

Comment: actually, I am asking about how you would like to navigate to the InCallContainer screen and from which other screen you are about to navigate to the InCallContainer screen ?

Comment: Ahh I see! Well I need to be able to navigate to `InCallContainer` programatically from a Redux Thunk - I have updated the question with more code - thanks very much.

Comment: The screen which I am navigating from can be any screen - the Redux thunk is called when an incoming call occurs

Comment: Then you have to create multiple stack navigators in which you have the  InCallContainer screen so you can navigate to it from any screens. check out the docs for more details : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what hooks you are using but React Navigation does expose its own hooks for lifecycle events.

Example that replaces the traditional useEffect hook:

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

function Profile() {
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      // Do something when the screen is focused

      return () => {
        // Do something when the screen is unfocused
        // Useful for cleanup functions
      };
    }, [])
  );

  return <ProfileContent />;
}
```

This will fire only when you navigate to the component and it becomes 'focus'ed within the context of React Navigation. React Navigation attempts to mount all views ahead of time for performance which is why the traditional React hooks can cause issues vs the focus style that React Navigation exposes.